# Wire to use with Sensors

Tags: sensor, wire, interference, shielding, soldering

I am trying to minimize interference in a sensor project. Can anyone recommend a good shielded wire I can solder into my board?

Comment: What sensor are you using, and what output does it give? (eg analog voltage from 0-5V, I2C, PWM, etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you are sending the sensor data some distance.  May not be the best but easily available is cat5 networking wire.  Ideal wire probably has twisted pair with a shield, just enough conductors to get by.  You may be able to find some audio wire set up this way.

If you can some processing of the sensor data prior to transmission can help.  For example converting to a differential signal, or taking a voltage and converting to a frequency.

Comment: You can also take a twisted pair from cat 5 and rap foil around it and ground the foil at both ends. This will do decent shielding. The differential signal will make it significantly more noise resistant after that step.

Answer (score 5):

Depending upon the length of the wire, and the type of signal you could try either twisted pair or shielded coaxial cable (coax). If you want to experiment you can find solid-core twisted pair in cat-5 cable (as russ_hensel says), and small diameter coax can be scrounged from microphone or headphone/earbud cables. The coax has a braided shield that you can connect to ground which shields the inner wires from interference. With twisted pair you use one wire for signal and the other for ground which minimizes (but can't eliminate) interference).

Answer (score 4):

Simple twisted pair (with no shielding) might be all you need.  The twists in the wire make noise common to both wires be out of phase with each other and thus cancel each other out.